# performance counters tips for server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, wcf, windows-server-2008, performancecounter

I have an mvc4 application that communicates to my sql server database via a wcf layer. Each layer is co located on the same server with the database located on a different server.

I am seeing CPU issues on my server which holds the applications, in particular with my mvc4 application. The server is windows server 2008 R2¬ running IIS7.5.

I would like to put some performance counters on my server to analyze where the problem on the server may be and is causing the high cpu problems.

I am new to setting up such and looking for pointers as to what counters to set up that may assist me, how I should analyze and best plan in gaining more knowledge on such.

Answer (score 0):

Performance counters are generally good for production monitoring. On dev environnement (and I suppose you are at this stage), there are many profiling tools & apis.

### On Sql Server

The best tool is [Sql Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx). You can find and diagnose slow-running queries by capturing all Transact-SQL statements and/or Sql Server Events.

### On Asp.net MVC

I highly suggest you install a profiler like [asp.net mini-profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) or [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). When browsing you website, this will tell you which controller/action/partial/ajax is slow and sometimes why.

Visual Studio includes a [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx). This let you measure, evaluate, and target performance-related issues in your code. It's fully integrated into the IDE. Once you have ran a performance session, several reports are available to help visualize and detect performance issues from the data gathered.

If you can't find why, you could run a load test using Visual Studio Web & Load Tests. You will rarely have performance issues for a single user, but for many concurrent users it's not generally the case.